# Clarification on properties of division

Tags: proof-verification

I'm learning proof by induction and I understand the property that

if $p|a$ and $p|b$ then $p|(a+b)$

Can someone elucidate why the following is always true (I'm assuming it's an extension of the property above):

In the below equation $a_1,a_2,k,l$ are all integers and $p$ is prime. We are assuming in our antecedent that $p|(a_1a_2)$

$a_2=pka_2+a_1a_2l$

Why is it clear from the above equation that $p|a_2$?

Comment: Say $a_1a_2=pm$.  Then $a_2=pka_2+pml=p(ka_2+ml)$.

Comment: Ah! Foolish me. Thanks!

Comment: $a_2 = pka_2 + a_1a_2l$.  We see $p|a_1a_2$ so $p|a_1a_2l$.  We see $p|pka_2$.  Add $a_1a_2l$ to $pka_2$ to get $ p|pka_2 + a_1a2l$$ = a_2$.  or as lulu points out ... or if $a_2 = pka_2 + a_1a_2l \implies pk + a_1l = 1$ (unless $a_2 =0$ and *everything* divides $0$).  As p doesn't divide 1 and p does divide pk, p doesn't divide $a_1l$ so p doesn't divide $a_1$.  As p is prime and indivisible $p|a_1a_2$ means either $p|a_1$ **OR** $p|a_2$.  As one is impossible the other must be true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$p$ divides the write hand side of the equation since $p \mid p k a_2$ (Because $p \mid p$) and $p \mid a_1 a_2 l$ (Because $p \mid a_1 a_2$) so $p$ also divides the sum (Just using the fact that you brought at first). Thus $p$ has to divide the left hand side which is $a_2$.

Hope that this is helpful.